# How can I check the value of a file in git before selecting Jenkins node?

Tags: xcode, git, jenkins

We have a `.xcode-version` file in our iOS repository, which fastlane is using to ensure that the correct version is being used to build the project. Different branches require different versions of Xcode to build and different nodes have different versions of Xcode installed. (We do have multiple installations of Xcode per node, but sometimes installing a new version of Xcode breaks an old installation, which is why we don't update all of them at once.) So every node cannot build every branch and we need to select node based on what is in the `.xcode-version` of that branch.

There's a bit of a chicken and egg problem, since that file isn't checked out until after the node has already been selected. However, that shouldn't be a problem, considering that Jenkins is checking out the `Jenkinsfile` before selecting a node and executing the pipeline. I don't see why that shouldn't be possible with any file.

How can I check out an arbitrary file from git in my pipeline and make arbitrary decisions (such as node selection) based on its content?

Comment: Did you find any success?

Comment: Sorry for not following up earlier. I haven't tried yet, because of some higher priority work. This is only an issue until all nodes have been upgraded, so since all nodes are upgraded now, this is not a priority for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A kind of dirty approach is to use the raw git url of the version file to download it in the workspace, read its content, and set the agent/node before entering the pipeline block.

For example:

```
node {
    withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'mylogin', variable: 'USERPASS')]) {
        sh 'curl -u "$USERPASS" https://raw.github.myorg/myrepo/${GIT_BRANCH}/.xcode-version -O .xcode-version'
        def version = readFile('.xcode-version').trim()
        switch(version) {
            case 'x.xx':
                agentLabel = 'agentX';
                break;
            case 'y.yy':
                agentLabel = 'agentY';
                break;
        }
    }
}
pipeline {
    agent {
        label agentLabel
    }
    stages {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bit crude, but looks like it should work. I was hoping that there would be some neat function in the git plugin.